# Unable to Edit Display Settings in 15.04

Tags: drivers, display, 15.04, system-settings

I just installed 15.04 on a new machine, and when I click on the gear icon in the top right, click `System Settings`, and click `Displays`, nothing happens. The window closes/crashes. How can I fix this?

I try it in the terminal, with `unity-control-center display`, but get this error:

`ERROR:gsd-rr-config.c:661:gsd_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gsd_rr_config_match (config, config))`

Perhaps it is a driver issue with my graphics card? I've never seen this error before.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I had to run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

Then restart:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now I have display settings and it detected my second monitor.

Comment: This helped me too! As for me, it wasn't ubuntu upgrade, I just added one more display (actually TV),  and my HDMI cable from monitor goes to TV and monitor connection was changed from HDMI to VGA. After that everything starts crashing and UI elements was looking ugly, disconnecting TV didn't help :(